# formik render props has been deprecated and will be deprecated in future versions

Tags: reactjs, formik

I just started using formik and i am using old codebase to write some code.
With this code I get this error:

```
            <Formik
              enableReinitialize={true}
              initialValues={InitialValues}
              onSubmit={(formData, formikProps) => this.handleSubmit(formData, formikProps)}
              render={formikProps => (
                  <View>
                      <FieldArray
                    name="address"
                    render={arrHelpers => (
                      <View>
                         
                        {formikProps.values.address &&
                          formikProps.values.address.length > 0 &&
                          formikProps.values.address.map((item, index) =>
                            this.renderForm(item, index, arrHelpers, formikProps)
                          )}
                      </View>
                    )}
                  />
                  <TouchableOpacity  onPress={formikProps.handleSubmit} style ={styles.buttonDown}>
                   <Text style={styles.submitButton}>Submit</Text>
                 </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
              )}
            />
```

Comment: where is the error?

Answer (score 4):

Check this out: https://formik.org/docs/migrating-v2#all-render-props-have-been-deprecated-with-a-console-warning

Instead of using a render prop, you would pass your render function as a child (as shown in the link above):

```
- <Field name="firstName" render={props => ....} />
+ <Field name="firstName">{props => ... }</Field>
```

Comment: This example is quite useless, we have been passing a function, not props =>

Answer (score 4):

Just close tags from `<Formik> ...props... </Formik>` and don't put inside the open tag from Formik. Be attention after, because you don't need more the "render=" and you need to put your "props" inside parenthesis.

Like this...

```
<Formik         
 enableReinitialize={true}
 initialValues={InitialValues}
 onSubmit={(formData, formikProps) => this.handleSubmit(formData, formikProps)}>
      {({formikProps}) => (
       <View>
          <FieldArray
           name="address"
           {({arrHelpers}) => (
              <View>                         
                {formikProps.values.address &&
                  formikProps.values.address.length > 0 &&
                  formikProps.values.address.map((item, index) =>
                    this.renderForm(item, index, arrHelpers, formikProps)
                  )}
              </View>
            )}
          />
          <TouchableOpacity  onPress={formikProps.handleSubmit} style={styles.buttonDown}>
           <Text style={styles.submitButton}>Submit</Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
      )}
 </Formik>
```

For Fields use the same way as the before answer.

In resume, just replace

```
<Formik render={(props) => ...} />   to   <Formik>{(props) => ...}</Formik>
```

Another example (more simple):

```
<Formik 
  
  onSubmit={onSubmit} 
  
  initialValues={{
      name: '',
      email: ''
    }}
    >
              
    {({ values }) => (
      <div className="container">
        <h1>Formulário Formik de exemplo</h1>
        <Form>
          <div>
            <label>Nome</label>
            <Field name="name" type="text" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Email</label>
            <Field name="email" type="email" />
          </div>
          <button className="btnSubmit" type="submit">Save</button>
        </Form>
      </div>
    )}
 </Formik>
```

In this link: [enter link description here](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik)  you can get documentation about that.

Answer (score 0):

with the use of spread, follow the example.

```
{ ...values => (
  <div className="container">
    <h1>Formulário Formik de exemplo</h1>
    <Form>
      <div>
        <label>Nome</label>
        <Field name="name" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Email</label>
        <Field name="email" type="email" />
      </div>
      <button className="btnSubmit" type="submit">Save</button>
    </Form>
  </div>
)}
```